# mvn -v show java information

Tags: java, maven

I have jdk8 installed.

**JAVA_HOME** is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60` (Installation path of JDK 8)

**PATH** variable is modified with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\maven\bin` (Installed path of maven 3.3.3)

When I type `mvn -v` in cmd, expected result do not show. Instead the result showing is equal to the result when I type `java` in cmd.
This error come only when I type `mvn -v` when cmd is inside D: drive. Works fine for C:

The result should get:(As in [here](https://maven.apache.org/install.html))

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T04:57:37-07:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Result I actually get:

```
D:\>mvn -v
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

Comment: Can you share the exact output you get from `mvn -v` and the result you expect to get?

Comment: Windows uses \ instead of / for path separators. Put `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in the path instead of `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`.

Comment: Have you installed a JDK and not a JRE?

Comment: I edited the post with result I get..

Comment: Actually I used \ not /. I will correct my question.. both jdk and jre are installed.

Comment: What happens when you type `mvn clean install`?

Comment: What do you see when you type `java -version` in the console? I assume you're using a windows console?

Comment: Try putting the path in `JAVA_HOME` within double quotes ("):

`set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60"`

Comment: java -version works fine..
`mvn clean install` also gives the same output. I typed only `mvn`. It also gives the same result.

Comment: After adding maven path in environment variables. you should run the commands in new command prompt window not the old one. Confirm if you are running in new one or old one.

Comment: Are you running the mvn command in a new session? Close the command window and open new one and type mvn -v ?

Comment: Sometimes writing the path like this helps: `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`

Comment: new window..
I'm behind a proxy. so I always set `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` variables in every restart of cmd

Comment: Close the console, open a new one, and type the following: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%` ... tell us what you see

Comment: When I type `mvn -v' when I'm in C:/ in cmd I get the expected result. Error comes only when I'm in D:/

Comment: Yeah, problem solved.. 
But I usually save projects in D:

Comment: So I would at this point probably just copy the configuration from the C: drive over to the D: drive, unless there is something preventing you from doing this.